# PHPUnit on MAMP - throwing a fatal error

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, phpunit

I am attempting to get phpUnit to function properly with MAMP on OS High Sierra and when trying to run a simple test it throws

"Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php'

I've looked at several StackOverflow articles and they suggest changing it to "autoload.php"

that then throws...

"Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php'"

This is on Zend Framework 1 with PHP 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Composer to install the PHPUnit, make sure you run it like this:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests/EmailTest
```

Or include `vendor/autoload.php` in your `phpunit.xml` like this:

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
```

See the [docs](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html).

Comment: Yes. I used Composer to install phpUnit. Using ./vendor returns a "directory not found"

Comment: I've found OS High Sierra to be quite the nightmare when trying to set up unit testing

Comment: @S.Edward How did you install PHPUnit? Did you run `composer install --dev phpunit/phpunit` or `composer global install  phpunit/phpunit` ?

Comment: It is installed globally. Here is the first error I'm getting... "Warning: require_once(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/lib/php/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/lib/php/Autoload.php on line 5"

Comment: @S.Edward Can you please update your question and add your project structure and the full command you use to run PHPUnit?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the version of the framework. 1.8 is just not going to work. Phpunit works just fine with a 3.0.3 Skeleton. I’m going to research migrating the codebase to 3.0.3

Thanks for you help